# lawnmower shaft is off aligment after hitting pipe stump

Tags: lawnmower

I have a Ariens self propelled lawnmower that I happend to hit a iron marker(pipe) with. When the blade hit the pipe, the lawnmower jolted and the engine stopped. I took a look and the blade still intact except for a nick on the edge. I replaced the flywheel key because it got broken when it hit the pipe.  the engine turns on but it vibrates in such a way the looks like the shaft might be out of aligment. is there a way to check the aligment? and if so, can it be reset? or is the mower finished?

Comment: I would try balancing the blade first.

Answer (score 0):

How are you certain it is the shaft? How did you measure the runout? What was the result?

For all the times I have hit things with lawnmowers - it is the blade / blade arm that gets bent  and I have had reasonable success with straightening the blade / blade arm...

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a way to straighten the crankshaft ,you will have to remove the engine from the mower, you can buy one or take it to a lawn mower repair shop if you buy one it comes with instructions